# Customize range heatmap.2

Tags: r, heatmap, gplots

I am using the heatmap.2 function from the "gplots" package and would like to tweak the vizual output.

I would like to get a symmetric color scheme and I have achieved that using the scale="row" option. However, when doing this, my range gets narrowed down to a small interval c(-1 , 1). The range of my data is c(-1.2 , 2.97), and  I would like the color scheme to capture the full resolution of my data. Can I specify the colour range to be e.g. c(-3,3) or is there another way to get a higher resolution of my data

This is my code

```
>head(hmdat[select,])
          Ind_B    Ind_Z     Ind_P
SVS1 -0.2176648 1.540470 -0.03700749
RHR2  0.3814377 1.425968  0.45827347
ADR1  0.7410964 1.062387  1.37050918
SPI1  0.2722683 1.324529  0.72636276
YAR1  0.7309389 1.278198  0.98776034
DDR2 -0.1727803 2.470086  0.74259052

>hmcol = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "RdBu"))(100)
>heatmap.2(hmdat[select,],scale="row", col = hmcol, trace="none", margin=c(7, 5),cexCol=0.9,cexRow=0.5,density.info="density")
```

generating this plot

[image: plot]

Another thing that I would like to fix is to remove the title of colour key and being able to specify manually the axis labels of the colour key. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't sound like you want to scale by row to me, then. Maybe try `scale = "none"` and setting `breaks` manually with something like `breaks = seq(-3, 3, length.out = 101)`

Comment: You are absolutely right. Using breaks does the job. Thanks

Comment: OK, I've added it as an answer so this question doesn't stay in the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `scale = "row"` will scale your data by row and doesn't keep your original, raw values so you should use `scale = "none"` if you want to preserve those.

You can set breaks manually by using the `breaks` argument. In this case, I think you could achieve what you're looking for by creating a sequence from -3 to 3, and setting `length.out` to one more than the number of colours you've defined (there needs to be 1 more breaks than colours):

```
heatmap.2(hmdat[select,],scale="none", col = hmcol, trace="none", margin=c(7, 5),cexCol=0.9,cexRow=0.5,density.info="density",breaks = seq(-3, 3, length.out = 101))
```

You might get warnings about there being no data for some values, and you may need to add `symbreaks = TRUE` to get the symmetrical effect you're looking for.

I don't think there is a simple option to change the labels of the color key, but you can try the solution in this question: [How to change the color key value in heatmap.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057777/how-to-change-the-color-key-value-in-heatmap-2)